# Is recursive Quick Sort faster than iterative in Python?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, benchmarking, quicksort

I am exploring Quick Sort, and I was wondering about the speed difference between the iterative and recursive versions of this algorithm in Python. Here are both of my implementations:

Iterative:

```
def qsort(l):
    callstack = collections.deque()
    callstack.appendleft(l)

    res = []
    while callstack:
        cur_list = callstack.popleft()
        if len(cur_list) == 1:
            res.insert(0, *cur_list)
            continue
        elif len(cur_list) == 0:
            continue

        pivot = cur_list[0]

        smaller = [x for x in cur_list[1:] if x <= pivot]
        greater = [x for x in cur_list[1:] if x > pivot]

        callstack.appendleft(smaller)
        callstack.appendleft([pivot])
        callstack.appendleft(greater)

    return res
```

Recursive:

```
def qsort(l):
    if len(l) < 2: return l

    pivot = l[0]
    smaller = [x for x in l[1:] if x <= pivot]
    greater = [x for x in l[1:] if x > pivot]

    return qsort(smaller) + [pivot] + qsort(greater)
```

I tested both of them with `timeit.repeat()`, with 20 repeats. The dataset was 50_000 integers long. For both sorts data was shuffled. I got these results:

```
Iterative qsort finished in  0.8948511301001417
Recursive qsort finished in  0.1437677413021447
```

These numbers are the mean results for those 20 repeats.

So we can clearly see a 7x speedup for recursive version. I have read about this on other sites, and for Java, let's say, it seems to be normal.
Recursion is known to be slow, because of its call stack, state memorizing and so on.
Is it normal for Python though?

Comment: It's likely `deque` is responsible for the slowdown. Try using a `list` instead. You always append left, never right, so there's no reason for a deque rather than a regular list.

Comment: Waaaaaait. Are you using the `deque` as a stack to emulate recursion? And you're wondering why your emulation of recursion is slower than actual recursion?

Comment: Mind, Python is _definitely_ not a language where function calls are particularly cheap -- of course, the calls you make to modify the `deque` also have that overhead.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to understand where the time goes, for anything, the best answer is to use a sampling profiler to measure that in practice. In this case, you might want one focused on profiling C applications to look at where the overhead is _inside the interpreter itself_.

Comment: @Stef I have just checked the same code with `list` instead of `deque`. Nothing has changed :)

Comment: @AleksandrNovik What you call "iterative quicksort" is definitely not what most people think of when they hear "iterative quicksort". You've just emulated recursion. You literally have a variable called `callstack`. Now you're asking us: "why is my homemade callstack slower than python's own callstack?". Well, possibly the people who implemented python's callstack weren't so bad after all.

Comment: Try implementing a really imperative version of quicksort, and compare it with the two implementations you already have.

Comment: @Stef yeah, you seem to be right. Implementations on web are different. Thanks.

Comment: Would help to include your timing code so that (1) we can see you didn't mess that one up (you wouldn't be the first) and (2) we could experiment with it ourselves.

Comment: @Stef Seems the `res.insert(0, ...)` is most responsible. After fixing that, the iterative version is just as fast as the recursive one in some testing of mine.

Comment: `res.insert(0, *cur_list)` requires moving the whole list backward to make room for the new element -- that's a linear operation every time and also traverses `cur_list` to unpack it into args. OP is benchmarking bad implementation. Use a `deque` if you need to push the front/unshift repeatedly like this.

Comment: @ggorlen Or use `append` instead (and put the three things onto `callstack` in reverse order). That's how I fixed that. It then has an *advantage* over the recursive one with its adding of lists, though. Although in my testing I used random numbers, so that repeated adding might not be that detrimental.